# Incompatible types very simple

Tags: java, types, jcreator

Im getting this error: incompatible types
k0= (i==0 * 2);
.........^

import java.util.Scanner;
public class pers5 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int k0,k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6,k7,k8,k9;
int produkt;

System.out.print("ange ett personnummer: ");
String indata = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    int nummer=indata.charAt(i) -48;
        System.out.print(indata.charAt(i)+ " ");
        System.out.println(indata.charAt(i));
//this code has lots of stuff between these two but its irrelevant.
k0= (i==0 * 2);
k1= (i==1 * 1);
k2= (i==2 * 2);
k3= (i==3 * 1);
k4= (i==4 * 2);
k5= (i==5 * 1);
k6= (i==6 * 2);
k7= (i==7 * 1);
k8= (i==8 * 2);
k9= (i==9 * 1);
produkt= k0+k1+k2+k3+k4+k5+k6+k7+k8+k9;
```

Answer (score 1):

`i==0` and subsequent calls return a boolean so it can't be assigned to k0 since it is of type `int`

Comment: That's not the case `i == 0 * 2` become `boolean` value.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the point

```
k0 = (i == 0 * 2); // i == 0 * 2 resulting a boolean
```

So `k0` mush be a `boolean`. You can use `boolean` instead of `int`

Comment: Ive done that now but now i get the error bad operand types for binary operator '+'
produkt= k0+k1+k2+k3+k4+k5+k6+k7+k8+k9;

Comment: @Marc you can't use `+`,`-` with `boolean`. make `produkt` `boolean` and use `&&(AND)` or `||(OR)`